# Complementary PWM issue on stm32

Tags: signals, stm32, pwm, stm32cubeide

I am generating 250khz PWM signal using STM32f401ccu6 (Blackpill) to drive high side and low side mosfets. I am using Timer 1 channel 1 along with its complementary PWM feature to utilize dead time feature. Currently I have generated the PWM signals at 250khz, but the CHN PWM is not opposite to the CH PWM. Both are starting from HIGH and transitioning to LOW. That means both are interfering by getting HIGH or LOW at same time. I tried to change the CHN polarity to HIGH to LOW in pinout configuration, but it is only inverting the duty cycle. The CHN PWM transition is not happening from LOW to HIGH. Also I tried by changing both CH and CHN polarity, idle state. Please let me know how to approach this.
Here is my code:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
 ******************************************************************************
 * @file           : main.c
 * @brief          : Main program body
 ******************************************************************************
 * @attention
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2022 STMicroelectronics.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
 * in the root directory of this software component.
 * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
 *
 ******************************************************************************
 */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
 * @brief  The application entry point.
 * @retval int
 */
int main(void)
{
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

    /* USER CODE END 1 */

    /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

    /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
    HAL_Init();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

    /* USER CODE END Init */

    /* Configure the system clock */
    SystemClock_Config();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

    /* USER CODE END SysInit */

    /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_TIM1_Init();
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start( &htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1 );
    HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Start( &htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1 );
    /* USER CODE END 2 */

    /* Infinite loop */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
    while (1)
    {
        /* USER CODE END WHILE */

        /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    }
    /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
 * @brief System Clock Configuration
 * @retval None
 */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
    RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

    /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
     */
    __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE2);

    /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
     * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
     */
    RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 50;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
    if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
     */
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
            |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

    if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}

/**
 * @brief TIM1 Initialization Function
 * @param None
 * @retval None
 */
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{

    /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 0 */

    TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
    TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
    TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig = {0};

    /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 1 */

    /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 1 */
    htim1.Instance = TIM1;
    htim1.Init.Prescaler = 0;
    htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    htim1.Init.Period = 200;
    htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
    htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
    if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim1, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
    sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
    sConfigOC.Pulse = 50;
    sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_LOW;
    sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
    sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
    sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
    if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
    sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
    sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
    sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;
    sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
    sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
    sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim1, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 2 */

    /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 2 */
    HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim1);

}

/**
 * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
 * @param None
 * @retval None
 */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

    /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
 * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
 * @retval None
 */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
    /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
    /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
    __disable_irq();
    while (1)
    {
    }
    /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
 * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
 *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
 * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
 * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
 * @retval None
 */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
    /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
    /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

[At CHN Polarity HIGH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiK1l.png)

[At CHN Polarity LOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTBlM.png)

[Required PWM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Gyo.png)

[Clock configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5K3x.png)

[Config img one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guP37.png)

[Config img two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMVcP.png)

[Timer 1 mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbOB5.png)